# R - match e adiciona string

Tags: r, regex

```
n <- c("alberto queiroz souza","bernardo josé silva","josé césar pereira","alberto, q-s.","alberto, queiroz souza","alberto, q. s.","alberto, q c", "bernardo, j. s.", "bernardo, j. silva", "josé, c. p.", "josé, c. pereira")
```

Devo encontrar cada elemento do vetor n, no df:

```
df <- data.frame(Titulo.1 = c("ALBERTO QUEIROZ SOUZA (ALBERTO, Q-S.) - ATUA NA EMPRESA.","B. J SILVA (BERNARDO, J. SILVA)", "JOSÉ CÉSAR PEREIRA (JOSÉ, C. P.)", "LENILTON FRAGOSO (FRAGOZO, LENILTON)","ALKMIM, MARCIO"),
                  Titulo.2 = c("BERNARDO JOSÉ SILVA (BERNARDO, J. S.)","ALBERTO QUEIROZ SOUZA (ALBERTO, QUEIROZ SOUZA)","JOSÉ CÉSAR PEREIRA (JOSÉ, C. PEREIRA)","LENILTON FRAGOSO (FRAGOZO, LENILTON)","ALKMIM, MARCIO"),
                  Titulo.3 = c("LENILTON FRAGOSO (FRAGOZO, L)","BERNARDO JOSÉ SILVA (BERNARDO, J. S.) - ATUA NA EMPRESA","ALBERTO QUEIROZ SOUZA (ALBERTO, Q. S.)","JOSÉ CÉSAR PEREIRA (J. C. P.)","ALKMIM, MARCIO"),
                  Titulo.4 = c("JOSÉ CÉSAR PEREIRA (JOSÉ, CÉZAR PEREIRA)","LENILTON FRAGOSO (FRAGOZO, LENILTON) - ATUA NA FIOCRUZ","ALKMIM, MARCIO","ALBERTO (ALBERTO, Q C)","BERNARDO JOSÉ SILVA (B, J. S.)"),
                  Titulo.5 = c("BERNARDO JOSÉ SILVA (BERNARDO, JS)","JOSÉ CÉSAR PEREIRA (JOSÉ, C. PEREIRA) - ATUA NA FIOCRUZ","LENILTON FRAGOSO (FRAGOZO, L.)","ALKMIM, MARCIO","ALBERTO QUEIROZ SOUZA (ALBERTO, Q-S.)"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

e quando encontrar devo adicionar "- atua na empresa", ficando assim "josé, c. p. - atua na empresa", por exemplo.

mas SE o match no df já apresentar o "- atua na empresa", obviamente não precisa.

estou tentando o match primeiro, com algo assim:

```
for (x in n) {
  result <- sapply(df, gsub, pattern = x, ...)
  #ou
  result <- sapply(df, str_replace, pattern = x, ...)
}
```

mas tá difícil.

Comment: Fernando, não entendi a lógica do seu data.frame. Você tem várias colunas com valores repetidos. Você quer fazer em todas as colunas. O nome pode aparecer mais de uma vez em uma coluna? Tem certeza que pretende manter cada nome em um formato?

Comment: No df, cada coluna é um Titulo de Artigo com os respectivos autores. Destes autores apenas um(em cada coluna), aparece com identificação que "atua na empresa" porém este mesmo autor aparece em outros títulos(colunas) mas sem a identificação que atua na empresa.

Comment: Assim, preciso verificar se ele aparece em mais Titulos e qdo encontrar verifico se há a identificação de "-  atua na empresa", se não, devo colocar "-  atua na empresa" na frente de seu nome.

Em cada coluna terá somente ele, mas em outras ele pode aparecer também (com ou sem a identif)

Comment: Veja 
"ALBERTO QUEIROZ SOUZA (ALBERTO, Q-S.) - ATUA NA EMPRESA." aparece com a identificação " - atua na empresa" somente na coluna Titulo.1

Nas outras colunas "ALBERTO QUEIROZ SOUZA (ALBERTO, Q. S.)" aparece mas sem a identificação.

Preciso colocar " - atua na empresa" em todos os "ALBERTO QUEIROZ SOUZA (ALBERTO, Q )" qm todos q encontrar.

Comment: Acho que um belo regex ia ajudar você.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código a seguir realiza o seguinte: para cada item de cada coluna, recupera os nomes, procura eles no vetor `n`, para os nomes encontrados verifica se já atuam na empresa, e decide adicionar esse texto no caso negativo. Como já falaram nos comentários, para ter melhores resultados tem que limpar seu banco.

```
textm<-"ATUA NA EMPRESA"
ndf<-as.data.frame(lapply(df,function(nc){#nc=df[,1]
  nct=nc
  ncm<-sapply(nc,function(nx)
    tolower(unlist(strsplit(nx," (",fixed=T))[1]) )
  enc=ncm%in%n
  emp=grepl(textm,nc[enc])
  nct[enc]<-ifelse(emp,nc[enc],paste(nc[enc]," - ",textm,".",sep=""))
  nct
  })
,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
ndf[,1]

[1] "ALBERTO QUEIROZ SOUZA (ALBERTO, Q-S.) - ATUA NA EMPRESA."
[2] "B. J SILVA (BERNARDO, J. SILVA)"                         
[3] "JOSÉ CÉSAR PEREIRA (JOSÉ, C. P.) - ATUA NA EMPRESA."     
[4] "LENILTON FRAGOSO (FRAGOZO, LENILTON)"                    
[5] "ALKMIM, MARCIO"
```